# Arguments to install Visual Studio silently with custom Installation path and components through Powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2017, powershell-remoting

All new to Powershell and trying to write a script that can do silent installation of Visual Studio 2017 on remote server with custom installation path and custom components using Invoke-Command and its -ScriptBlock parameter. 
Able to install visual studio silently but without providing a install path and custom component list as I am not sure how to pass arguments for thsoe. Tried various  Saw no help specific to this anywhere.

param (

```
    $session = "New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $mycredentials",
    $SourceFile = "\\server\D$\Somefolder\vs.exe",
    $Destination = "D:\Somefolder\"
    )


Write-Host "Installing Visual Studio"

Copy-Item -FromSession $session -Path $SourceFile -Destination $destination -Force

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Start-Process $Destination\vs.exe -ArgumentList '--quiet', '--installPath "C\VS\"' -Wait

    }

      Exit-PSSession
```

Tried different variations for installation path like --installPath "D:\Somefolder\", -installPath "D:\Somefolder\", -install 'D:\Somefolder\' , even thought of passing arguments through a varible but not sure how will it work in this scenario.
Henceforthe landed here with no success and even saw no help specific to this scenario anywhere.

Comment: I think `$Destination\vs.exe` is wrong because $Destination already ends in a backslash, so you will end up with `D:\SomeFolder\\vs.exe`.  To avoid things like that, better use `$exeToRun = Join-Path $Destination "vs.exe"` and use that (as in `Start-Process -FilePath $exeToRun`). Also, your code shows an incorrect path for the `installPath` argument. That one is missing a colon and should be `C:\VS\`

Comment: @Theo: While using `Join-Path` is a good recommendation, note that `\\ ` (or `//`) as separators in paths do work.

Comment: Just want to throw out there that while you *can* do remote installation of a program over Powershell, depending on how often you need to do this in your environment, this won't scale well and is a candidate reason to consider implementing a configuration management solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following (untested) - note the comments that relate to what you tried:

```
param (
  # Use $(...) to use a command's output as a parameter default value.
  # By contrast assigning "..." only assigns a *string*.
  $session = $(New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $mycredentials),
  # To be safe, better to `-escape $ inside "..." if it's meant to be a literal.
  $SourceFile = "\\server\D`$\Somefolder\vs.exe",
  $Destination = "D:\Somefolder"
)

Write-Host "Installing Visual Studio"

Copy-Item -FromSession $session -Path $SourceFile -Destination $destination -Force

# You don't need the session anymore now that you've copied the file.
# Normally you'd call
#     Remove-PSSession $session
# However, given that the session may have been passed as an argument, the caller
# may still need it.

# With the installer present on the local machine, you can invoke
# Start-Process locally - no need for a session.
Start-Process -Wait $Destination\vs.exe -ArgumentList '--quiet', '--installPath "C:\VS"'

# No need for Exit-PSSession (which is a no-op here), given that 
# you haven't used Enter-PSSession.
```